# Check if LINQ entity of unknown type exists in its respective table

Tags: vb.net, linq

Heres an interesting issue, I'm trying to check if a LINQ Entity exists in its table, but at design time I dont know what type that entity is. So I figure I'll just get the table, and try the Contains method on it. But I cant get the table in such a way that I can query it at design time.

I've tried the `GetTable` method on the datacontext, but I dont know how to cast it to the appropriate type when using `GetTable(Of)`. `GetTable(Type)` works, I just use `Entity.GetType()`, but then I don't know how to query the `ITable` thats returned.

To try and cast the `ITable` to something useable, I created an interface(`IWhatever`) that could implement properties that are native to all of my entities I would encounter. I then attempted a `CType(GetTable(Entity.GetType()), IEnumerable(Of IWhatever)))` No luck.

Any ideas, or am I just going about this completely wrong?

Example:

```
Public Function EntityExists(ByVal Entity As Object, ByVal DataContext As MyDataContext) As Boolean
    Dim T as Type = Entity.GetType()

    Dim EntityITable as ITable = DataContext.GetTable(T)

    'Do something to see if ITable contains Entity    

End Function
```

Comment: It's unclear what you know, and what you don't know at design time.  Could you give us an example of what you expect a call to this function would look like?

Comment: Ahh, sure. Edited the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the vb.net syntax, so I'll have to do this is C#:

```
public bool EntityExists<T>(T Entity, MyDataContext DataContext)
{    
    ITable<T> EntityITable  = DataContext.GetTable<T>();
    return EntityITable.Contains(Entity);
}
```

The Vb.net, I imagine, would be something like:

```
Public Function EntityExists(Of TEntity)(ByVal Entity As TEntity, _
                 ByVal DataContext As MyDataContext) As Boolean 

    Dim EntityITable as ITable(of TEntity) = DataContext.GetTable(of TEntity)()

    Return  EntityITable.Contains(Entity)
End Function
```

Comment: Ahh, yea thats what I'm lookin for. A little more research into it and it works now. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The End Result:

```
Public Function EntityExists(Of TEntity As Class)(ByVal Entity As TEntity, ByVal DataContext As System.Data.Linq.DataContext)

    Dim EntityITable As System.Data.Linq.Table(Of TEntity) = DataContext.GetTable(Of TEntity)()
    If EntityITable.Contains(Entity) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End Function
```

It can be used by:

```
Dim Exists As Boolean = EntityExists(Entity, DataContext)
```